# NextJs Sending data from Axios to Danfo

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, axios, danfojs

I am working on a NextJs page.
I have used axios with usestate and useeffect to retreive json data from a web api into a const state
apiData'.

```
.then((res) => {
   setApiData(res.data.Projects);
     console.log(res.data.Projects);
 })
```

Here is the console.log output:

```
[
 {
 Name: Project1,
 Number: DM-01
 },
 {Name: Project 2, Number: DM 02}
]
```

Now, I am able to console.log or apiData.map the data in the nextjs application.
But I am unable to map the apiData to danfo dataframe:

```
const df = new Danfo.DataFrame(apiData)

console.log(df.columns)
```

I and trying to assign the json received from axios to danfo dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

To print denfo dataframe, you should use `df.print()` function. Also make sure your `apiData` is not `null` before assigning it to `df`.

```
if(apiData) {
  const df = new Danfo.DataFrame(apiData);
  df.print();
}
```